# How do I get a variable from another class in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, variables

How do I set selectedPlayer to the value of position from my other class?

I've read a bunch of similar questions on here, but I keep running into conflicts with my variables and functions.

ScoreList.java

```
public class ScoreList extends Activity {

    Integer selectedPlayer = 0;
}
```

ScoreListAdapter.java

```
public class ScoreListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Score> {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final OnClickListener lsScoreView = new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //send position to main class here
              }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: What value of position from which other class?

Comment: getView in ScoreListAdapter gets passed int position and I want that value to get sent to the selectedPlayer variable in ScoreList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set selectedPlayer as static:

```
public class ScoreList extends Activity {

  static Integer selectedPlayer = 0;
}
```

This way,You can refer selecterPlayer using class name as it does not belong to any object of the class.

ScoreListAdapter.java

```
    public class ScoreListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Score> {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final OnClickListener lsScoreView = new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       ScoreList.selectedPlayer;//You can use selectedPlayer here
                  }
            };

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used your code, changing the second part to "ScoreList.selectedPlayer = position;" and it gives me an error I was getting earlier: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable position inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: make position final like,  ...getView(final int position, View..

Answer (score 0):

Options...

1. Pass `ScoreList` in as a parameter to the `ScoreListAdapter` constructor and set it as an instance variable that you can refer to in `ScoreListAdapter.getView`.
2. Pass `ScoreList` in as a parameter to the `getView` method.